# heroku staging or new app in heroku for staging?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, production, staging

What are thoughts around creating a staging environment for my app or should i create a second app on heroku for staging? Which one is better, or preferred?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Second app - add the git remote of the new app to your repo so you can deploy to it from a single code base.

Read more at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments

Comment: aside from that benefit, doesn't it make it more difficult for you to duplicate your database in this new second testing app? wouldn't you need to create fake data so you can see how new features play with existing data?

Comment: typically I use `heroku db:pull` (from my production app) into my staging app with a `heroku db:push` - deploy code to staging, run any migrations and see what breaks. If it's a big DB then pg:backups is used.

Comment: would it be an issue if the local database is mysql and heroku is on postgre when pulling and pushing the db?

Comment: nope, that's exactly what `heroku db:push` does. It doesn't matter what the local database is, sqlite, pg, mysql - it uses TAPS (https://github.com/ricardochimal/taps) behind the scenes.